# simplePie can't get specific RDF field from a RSS

Tags: php, rss, rdf, simplepie

I'm trying to parse a RSS based on simplePie and and the RSS which I want to parse is based on RDF.

and has some particular fields such as : "creator" / "identifier" / etc...

I read the simplePie document according how to get specific field from an rss and write the following code (mostlythe same as simplePie example):

the simplePie document link :

> http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_item_tags

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://www.nature.com/nchem/current_issue/rss');
$feed->enable_cache(false);
$success = $feed->init();
//$feed->handle_content_type('text/plain');

if ($success)
{
    if ($item = $feed->get_item(0))
    {
        // This is probably a bad example because we already support <media:content> natively, but it shows you how to parse through the nodes.
        $media_group = $item->get_item_tags('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#', 'rdf');
        $media_content = $media_group[0]['child']['http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#']['content'];
       // $file = $media_content[0]['attribs']['']['url'];
       // echo $file;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Error: Could not get first item';
    }
}
else
{
    echo $feed->error();
}
```

the media_group and media_content(of course) are always returning NULL

how can I get specific field from RSS?

Comment: +1. this is giving me a headache right now. Yes non-standard feeds might be a pain or bad practice but is it really better to chuck extra stuff in the `<description>` and bugger around trying to parse something meaningful out of it on the other end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-standard feeds can give SimplePie and me headaches. You can get the raw XML from SimplePie and then use something else to parse/manipulate it. I've done that in some cases using SimpleHTMLDom...